# Creating download links for Amazon Kindle

Tags: php, download, kindle

I noticed that Kindle recognizes the file types by their extension. So, I wrote a small script on my website that downloads a file, adds ".azw" extension and provide a download link. It works well sometimes but...

The problem is that I'm not a PHP developer and I'm sure the script is not written in the best way. A problem is that the script doesn't download some files (exe) but loads another exe. It gives an error saying that it cannot find the file and creates a `filename.exe.azw` file with 0 length. This issue appears only on the Kindle, but on the PC it's ok.

Also it seems that it can download only files smaller than 9 Mb.

The code is here:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['link'])) {
?>
        <form method="post" action="file.php">
            <p>
                Enter link: http://
                <input type="text" name="link" size="20"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
            </p>
        </form>
<?php
    } else {
        $remote   = 'http://' . $_POST['link'];
        $download = download($remote);
        echo 'Download: <a href="' . $download . '">' . $download . '</a>';
    }

    function download($url) {
        $lastDashPos = strrpos($url, '/');
        $local = substr($url, $lastDashPos + 1, strlen($url) - $lastDashPos) . '.azw';

        $handle = file_get_contents($url);
        file_put_contents($local, $handle);

        return $local;
    }
?>
```

The script is at http://forexsb.com/test/file.php if you want to test it.

Comment: You might have more luck if you ask a specific question rather than just "fix my code"

Comment: Why don't you try a rename instead of slurping the file?